# Unity - Resolution of the dependency failed (without registering)

Tags: c#, unity-container

I'm getting an error on this line of code:

```
    using (IMaterialClient rawMaterialServiceProxy =
ServerUtility.Container.Resolve<IMaterialClient>())
```

The error:

> Resolution of the dependency failed... The current type, Xxx, is an
>   interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

I'm not registering a concrete IMaterialClient. In the Pluralsight video I just watched, they said that you don't have to register every type because Unity will find an implementation if one wasn't specified. Has that changed? Am I missing something? Why won't that resolve? The assembly with the actual IMaterialClient implementation is in the bin folder when running this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they said that about Unity, they're wrong. Unity will resolve a concrete type (`.Resolve<MyClass>`), but interfaces have to be explicitly registered by associating them with concrete types.

There are extensions such as [Unity Auto Registration](http://autoregistration.codeplex.com/) to provide those features; I have no experience with them.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not aware of that feature in Unity. As far as I know, it will happily resolve unregistered concrete types, but has to have had a concrete type registered for any abstract types or interfaces. Best bet is to register it:

```
ServerUtility.Container.RegisterType<IMaterialClient, ConcreteMaterialClient>();
```